# What's the difference between slob vs lazy?

Tags: difference

I couldn't find the difference in Google and the dictionaries entries are similar. Actually one definition included the other term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is the part of speech.  "Lazy" is an adjective

> He is a lazy man.

Slob is a noun

> He is a slob.

Slob can also include "dirty" or "too lazy to keep clean"

> You're such a slob, you're wearing the same shirt that you spilled ketchup on last Friday.

Both can negative, but "slob" is more an insult than lazy.  It is good to say

> I had a lazy Sunday afternoon.

but If you say "I was a slob on Sunday afternoon" that is negative

Comment: Thank you James! You were the opposite of being lazy with your prompt answer. Next time I better pay more attention to the word types, so I don’t turn into a searching slob.